# Linear executable (LE) file format documentation

Tags: windows, file-format

Like in topic, but I'm exactly interested of this field :

HT editor output

```
--- VxD only ---
offset of win-resource data
```

I would like to know how exactly looks this structure pointed by this offset.
Really, I spent nearly entire day today and could not find proper documentation o_0.

Answer (score 0):

The "win-resource" data pointed to is in the Windows 16-bit .RES resource format. Only the VS_VERSION_INFO resource is included. It's not used by the VxD itself, and you don't need to provide it if you're creating your own VxD.

The old Windows 16-bit .RES format isn't very well documented. This site documents the similar but apparently not identical OS/2 .RES format: http://www.edm2.com/0206/resources.html